# redirección login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, login

Mi controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\panelPadre;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Common;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PanelController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(['padreauth' => 'verified']);
    }
    public function index() {
        return view('padre/home/index');
    }
}
```

En el archivo kernel.php agregue un middleware:

```
'padreauth' => \App\Http\Middleware\PadreLogin::class
```

El middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class PadreLogin extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request) {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login-padre');
        }
    }
}
```

en web.php:

```
Route::resource('/padre', 'panelPadre\PanelController@index');
Route::get('login-padre', 'Auth\LoginPadreController@showLoginForm')->name('login-padre');
```

Cuando un usuario trate de ingresar a la ruta /padre se supone que tendría que redireccionarlo a /login-padre, pero no, lo que hace es redireccionarlo a /login (que es otra vista para otro tipo de usuario).
Hice el middleware y lo declare en el controlador, no se porque me sigue mandando a /login alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber entendido tu pregunta...
Prueba poner la ruta de tu segundo login (app.com/algo) dentro del middleware auth

```
Route::group(["middleware" => 'auth'], function(){
        //aquí tu ruta
});
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que se más específico en su pregunta y si la cambia, procedemos a responder. Por favor, haz [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad.

Comment: @Agustin cree otro middleware exactamente igual al de auth con la diferencia de la ruta que se manda pero ni así funciona, no se si lo tengo que declarar en otro archivo o lo estoy llamando mal